# Duplicate data due to "Access-Control-Max-Age"

Tags: java, rest, http-headers

I have created a rest service which is accessible by mobile application. To enable app to access rest service i have added below mention code. I am sending json data while calling my web service. I am calling my rest services after every 30 min. Now the issue is my json request is saved more than 1 time in db some case.
I am not sure but this may be due to  "Access-Control-Max-Age".

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
```

Rest service code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savRes", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
SaveDataRes saveDateRes(@RequestBody ResDate resData,
        final HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
...
//calling DAO to save data
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this? Could you provide your backend code, which persist your data, as well?

Comment: I am using simple spring jdbctemplate to save data. but from the timestamp i guess that the request is sent twice in some case.

Comment: Actually the `Access-Control-Max-Age` just tells the browser, how long it can cache the preflight request. The preflight request is just done for checking, if following CORS-request is allowed. If server allows CORS from given domain in preflight request, the actual request from browser is executed. So there must be some other issues, probably with your backend code. But I don't see enough from your provided code.